# Resolving a promise on iteration

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, es6-promise

I wrote some code to send out either a text message or push notification on an array of phone numbers. However, I am having an issue figuring out where to resolve the promise, while trying to avoid getting a multiple success/error error. GuestDigits is an array of phone numbers. Any thoughts or comments would be greatly appreciated.

```
  Parse.Cloud.define('sendOutNotifications', function(request, response) {

  var owner = request.user;
  var ownerNumber = owner.get('phoneNumber');
  var guestlistId = request.params.guestlistId;
  var guestDigits = request.params.guestDigits;
  var eventName = request.params.eventName;
  var promotionTime = request.params.promotionTime;
  var firstName = owner.get('firstName');

  guestDigits.forEach(function(guestDigit) {

    var queryUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    queryUser.equalTo('phoneNumber', guestDigit);

    queryUser.find().then(function(result) {

      if (result.length > 0) {
        Parse.Cloud.run('sendPushNotification', {
          user: JSON.stringify(result[0]),
          firstName: firstName,
          eventName: eventName,
          promotionTime: promotionTime
        });
      } else {
        Parse.Cloud.run('sendTextMessage', {
          firstName: firstName,
          phoneNumber: guestDigit
        });
      };
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should promisify the loop in your code. Every query will return a promise which you can chain furthur using `.then()` blocks. You add all these promises to an array and after your gone through the loop, you wait for all of them to be fulfilled.

```js
Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {
    var promises = [];    

    guestDigits.forEach(function(guestDigit) {

        var queryUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
        queryUser.equalTo('phoneNumber', guestDigit);

        promises.push(queryUser.find().then(function(result) {

            if (result.length > 0) {
                return Parse.Cloud.run('sendPushNotification', {
                       user: JSON.stringify(result[0]),
                       firstName: firstName,
                       eventName: eventName,
                       promotionTime: promotionTime });
            } else {
                return Parse.Cloud.run('sendTextMessage', {
                       firstName: firstName,
                       phoneNumber: guestDigit });
            }
       }));
   });

   // wait for all the promises to be fulfilled
   return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

}).then(function() {
        // success
    }, function (error) {
        // error
}));
```